# Different Traceroute Endings

Tags: networking, internet, dns, traceroute

Am trying to understand why Trace-route endings are different from on site to another. This below three outputs has been constant for long period of time.

Using: http://centralops.net/co/Traceroute.aspx

```
user:   anonymous [41.69.91.120]

balance:    47 units
    log in | account info
        CentralOps.net

Tracing route to 41.69.91.120 [41.69.91.120]...

hop     rtt     rtt     rtt         ip address  fully qualified domain name
1   0   0   0       208.101.16.73   208.101.16.73-static.reverse.softlayer.com
2   0   0   0       66.228.118.157  ae11.dar02.sr01.dal01.networklayer.com
3   0   0   0       173.192.18.212  ae6.bbr02.eq01.dal03.networklayer.com
4   0   0   0       157.238.224.229     ae-11.r01.dllstx04.us.bb.gin.ntt.net
5   0   0   0       129.250.3.232   ae-5.r08.dllstx09.us.bb.gin.ntt.net
6   0   1   0       173.241.131.121     ae16.dal33.ip4.gtt.net
7   130     130     137         89.149.186.42   xe-0-2-0.mrs10.ip4.gtt.net
8   162     161     161         77.67.95.114    telecom-egypt-gw.ip4.gtt.net
9   *   *   *           
10  164     164     167         41.33.197.150   host-41.33.197.150.tedata.net
11  *   *   *           
12  194     192     193         41.69.91.120    

Trace complete

-- end --
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

Using: http://traceroute.fmc.lu/cgi-bin/traceping.pl

```
Traceroute for 41.69.91.120     Date: Friday 07 November 2014
Hour: 14:48:31 UTC  

traceroute to 41.69.91.120 (41.69.91.120), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

 1  FMC_SCHNADT_ROUTER (80.92.66.1)  0.216 ms  0.280 ms  0.351 ms
 2  80-92-83-199.ip.dclux.com (80.92.83.199)  0.212 ms  0.215 ms  0.219 ms
 3  80-92-83-193.ip.dclux.com (80.92.83.193)  0.455 ms  0.447 ms  0.440 ms
 4  Port-c.410.asr1.AMS2.gblx.net (64.208.205.149)  7.477 ms  7.559 ms  7.630 ms
 5  xe5-0-2-10G.scr4.AMS2.gblx.net (67.17.71.217)  14.851 ms xe5-0-2-10G.scr3.AMS2.gblx.net (67.17.71.213)  8.494 ms  8.495 ms
 6  ae0.ar9.AMS2.gblx.net (67.16.146.126)  8.491 ms ae1.ar9.AMS2.gblx.net (67.16.130.182)  14.898 ms ae0.ar9.AMS2.gblx.net (67.16.146.126)  8.483 ms
 7  4.68.110.197 (4.68.110.197)  10.987 ms  7.838 ms  10.958 ms
 8  ae-2-5.edge1.Marseille1.Level3.net (4.69.148.14)  31.142 ms  28.063 ms ae-1-4.edge1.Marseille1.Level3.net (4.69.148.10)  31.357 ms
 9  TE-DATA-EGY.edge1.Marseille1.Level3.net (212.73.206.14)  77.422 ms  77.398 ms  80.620 ms
10  * * *
11  host-41.33.197.154.tedata.net (41.33.197.154)  77.467 ms host-41.33.197.150.tedata.net (41.33.197.150)  83.444 ms host-41.33.197.154.tedata.net (41.33.197.154)  77.584 ms
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

Using: Looking Glass Results - dal33.ip4.tinet.net

```
Date: Fri Nov 7 14:48:35 2014 CET

Query:
Argument(s): 41.69.91.120

traceroute to 41.69.91.120 (41.69.91.120), 12 hops max, 40 byte packets

 1  xe-7-2-0.mrs10.ip4.gtt.net (89.149.182.230)  132.071 ms xe-5-1-0.mrs10.ip4.gtt.net (89.149.182.226)  129.878 ms xe-10-2-0.mrs10.ip4.gtt.net (89.149.185.153)  132.636 ms
 2  telecom-egypt-gw.ip4.gtt.net (77.67.95.114)  161.193 ms  220.415 ms  234.411 ms
 3  * * *
 4  host-41.33.197.150.tedata.net (41.33.197.150)  174.757 ms  173.153 ms host-41.33.197.146.tedata.net (41.33.197.146)  185.153 ms
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *

{master}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

Using: http://traceroute.monitis.com/

```
Source
United States

1ip-10-170-4-3.us-west-1.com1 ms1 ms1 ms

2ip-10-1-78-1.us-west-1.comp11 ms0 ms1 ms

3100.64.28.1311 ms2 ms1 ms

4216.182.236.1061 ms1 ms1 ms

572.21.222.162 ms1 ms2 ms

6205.251.229.1683 ms2 ms2 ms

7205.251.229.1842 ms2 ms2 ms

8xe-10-2-0.mrs10.ip4.gtt.net176 ms173 ms172 ms

9telecom-egypt-gw.ip4.gtt.ne199 ms199 ms177 ms

10telecom-egypt-gw.ip4.gtt.ne199 ms0 ms0 ms

11host-41.33.197.154.tedata.n278 ms0 ms0 ms

12host-41.33.197.146.tedata.n277 ms277 ms277 ms

13
no response

14
no response

15
no response

16
no response

17
no response

18
no response

19
no response

20
no response

21
no response

22
no response

23
no response

24
no response

25
no response

26
no response

27
no response

28
no response

29
no response

30
no response

Destination
41.69.91.120
----------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

[image: http://www.as3257.net/lg/]
[image: http://www.as3257.net/lg/]
[image: http://centralops.net/co/Traceroute.aspx]
[image: New-Trace]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracert from here completes nicely:

```
C:\>tracert 41.69.91.120

Tracing route to 41.69.91.120 over a maximum of 30 hops
```

...

```
  3     8 ms     6 ms     6 ms  vnn-rc0001-cr101-irb-225.core.as9143.net [213.51.168.226]
  4     8 ms     9 ms     9 ms  asd-tr0042-cr101-ae6-0.core.as9143.net [213.51.158.78]
  5     8 ms     8 ms     6 ms  ix-8-0.tcore1.AV2-Amsterdam.as6453.net [195.219.194.37]
  6     9 ms     9 ms     9 ms  195.219.194.90
  7    33 ms    32 ms    33 ms  xe-0-0-0.mrs10.ip4.gtt.net [89.149.182.54]
  8    74 ms    75 ms    76 ms  telecom-egypt-gw.ip4.gtt.net [77.67.95.114]
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10    75 ms    77 ms   106 ms  host-41.33.197.146.tedata.net [41.33.197.146]
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12   102 ms   107 ms   100 ms  41.69.91.120
```

It looks like two of your online tracert sites are not handling timeouts very well (retrying instead of going to the next hop)

Comment: Have aded new-trace and it did not end right, also no time-out was detected. Routing beyond NL is not visible.

Comment: And your point is? Every online tool is different ... try http://traceroute.monitis.com/index.jsp?url=41.69.91.120&testId=514153

Comment: Traceroute to a single destination can be different depending on the route the traceroute source uses to get to the destination IP. If the upstream router for your subnet has multiple upstream interfaces, would you expect the ISP to only use one of them to provide consistent traceroute results?

Comment: Multiple routes are understandable. My question was regarding the end device which suppose to be one device. only on trace utility (        CentralOps.net) ended at destination.

Comment: @user176105 It depends how previous hops are configured. See [bgp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol#Per-neighbor_decisions). bgp is used to configure routing. With a different route the intermediate devices may be configured to not respond to pings (and therefore stop traceroute)